# Creating a Pivot Table in VBA : Run Time Error '1004' (Unable to get the PivotTables property of Worksheet class)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am using Excel 2010 and I am using the following VBA code to create Pivot table :-

```
Sub addFields()

  With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)

    With .PivotFields("Name")
      .Orientation = xlRowField
      .Position = 1
    End With

    With .PivotFields("Location")
      .Orientation = xlPageField
      .Position = 1
    End With

   .AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Order Amount"), _
     "Sum of Amount", xlSum

  End With

End Sub
```

Following is the data on *Sheet1* where I want to create a Pivot Table.

```
Name     Order Amount   Location
Grace    1200000        New York
Tom      2000000        New York
Madhuri  5000000        Delhi
Hari     6000000        Delhi
Raj      7000000        Delhi
Victoria 8000000        New York
```

But I am getting a:

> Run Time Error 1004 : Unable to get PivotTables property of Worksheet class.

Can anyone please suggest on this?

Comment: What line is the error occurring on?

Comment: You're already trying to work on the Pivot table object but you haven't created it yet. First you need to create the pivot table cache and then  that is the time you can use above code.